# How can I use <html> templates in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to replace my in-code template with html file. How can I do it?

```
Greeting.annotations = [
    new angular.ComponentAnnotation({
        selector: 'greeting'
    }),
    new angular.ViewAnnotation({
        template: '<h1>Hello!</h1>'
    })
];
```

I want something like this

```
template: 'path/to/my/template.html'
```

I use Angular2 and ES5.

Comment: `templateUrl : 'path/to/my/template.html'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As part of the `ComponentAnnotation` there is a property `templateUrl` which you can point at an HTML file.

- template - points at raw HTML
- templateUrl - points at a URL containing the HTML

This is the same as angular 1.x directive definition object

You can find more information about component's properties [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentMetadata-class.html)

**NOTE** - *docs are still a work in progress*

Answer (score 1):

As provided by Angular officials you can import external HTML file by using `TemplateUrl` in `ComponentAnnotation` as well as in `ViewAnnotation` too. moreover you have option to use `Template` in the same `ComponentAnnotation` and `ViewAnnotation`.

## update:

@view has been deprecated so only way to provide html is using @component like this

```
@component({
  ..
  template: `<h1>This is inline template </h1>`
   or
  templateUrl : 'URL FOR your html page';
  ..........
})
....
```

Answer (score -4):

Probably in your template you can refer to another HTML file, such as:

```html
<ng-include src="'templates/[new template file].html'"></ng-include>
```

Comment: This appears to be for Angular 1 not Angular 2.